# Why does the ordering of it functions matter in this jest test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following component...

```
export default class TextInput extends PureComponent<TextInputProps> {

  private handleOnChange = (event: OnChangeEvent): void => {
    if (!this.props.disabled && this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange(event)
    }
  }

  private handleOnBlur = (event: OnBlurEvent): void => {
    if (!this.props.disabled && this.props.onBlur) {
      this.props.onBlur(event)
    }
  }

  public render(): ReactNode {
    return (
      <Styled.TextInput
        id={this.props.id}
        type={this.props.type}
        onChange={this.handleOnChange}
        onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
        disabled={this.props.disabled}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

And am trying to test the handleOnChange function using the following test...

```
const mockOnChange = jest.fn((): void => { })
const mockOnBlur = jest.fn((): void => { })

const minHandlerProps ={
  id: 'test',
  type: 'text',
  onChange: mockOnChange,
  onBlur: mockOnBlur,
}

describe('handleOnChange', () => {
  it('Should not call the onChange prop when it\'s been passed and TextInput is disabled', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TextInput {...minHandlerProps} disabled={true} />)
    const instance = wrapper.instance()

    instance.handleOnChange()
    expect(minHandlerProps.onChange).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

  it('Should call the onChange prop when it\'s been passed and TextInput is not disabled', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TextInput {...minHandlerProps} />)
    const instance = wrapper.instance()

    instance.handleOnChange()
    expect(minHandlerProps.onChange).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

The tests pass when they are in this order, but if I swap the order around the **should not call the onChange prop** test fails.

Is this because in this instance, the onChange prop has already been called in the first it()?

Am I supposed to write a separate describe for this?

I've console logged that the props are passing correctly and it looks as though they are, so I'm at a loss as to this behaviour. Thanks anyone who can shed some light on it.

Comment: Because they share a single instance of each mock function. You need to either clear the state of [one](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear) or [all](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestclearallmocks) of the mocks (or [configure](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#clearmocks-boolean) that to happen), or create a new one for each test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks! I can't mark your comment as the correct answer, but if you do add it as an answer I can mark it as correct below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defining the mock functions outside the describe block, you share a single instance of each between all tests. This means you see calls from other tests, so your test are order-dependent (a *very* bad thing for unit tests).

There are various solutions to this:

1. Create a new instance for each test, e.g. in a `beforeEach`:

   ```
   describe('handleOnChange', () => {
     let minHandlerProps;
     let mockOnBlur;
     let mockOnChange;

     beforeEach(() => {
       mockOnChange = jest.fn((): void => { })
       mockOnBlur = jest.fn((): void => { })

       minHandlerProps = {
         id: 'test',
         type: 'text',
         onChange: mockOnChange,
         onBlur: mockOnBlur,
       }
     });

     ...
   });
   ```
2. Reset each one explicitly between tests with [`mockClear`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear):

   ```
   describe('handleOnChange', () => {       
     beforeEach(() => {
       mockOnBlur.mockClear();
       mockOnChange.mockClear();
     });

     ...
   });
   ```
3. Reset all mocks explicitly between tests with [`clearAllMocks`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestclearallmocks):

   ```
   describe('handleOnChange', () => {       
     beforeEach(() => {
       jest.clearAllMocks();
     });

     ...
   });
   ```
4. Get Jest to reset all mocks between tests, by setting [`clearMocks`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#clearmocks-boolean) to `true` in your configuration.

---

As a side note, I would *not* recommend testing that invoking `handleOnChange` on the instance invokes the mocked function prop. That's the *implementation* - the *behaviour* of the component is that the callback is invoked when the `Styled.TextInput` changes, or better yet when some interaction with *that* component occurs. Simulating these events leaves you less coupled to your current implementation.