# Test ActivatedRoute params subscription in Jest unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, observable, angular-observable

I need to test if a method is called with the correct params based on the results of an ActivatedRoute subscription.

Template:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  let projectKey: string;
  const projectKeyFromStorage = this.getProjectKeyFromStorage();
  this.route.params.subscribe(param => {
    if (!param.key) {
      if (!projectKeyFromStorage) {
        this.switchToErrorDisplay('NO_PROJECT_KEY');
      }
      projectKey = projectKeyFromStorage;
    } else {
      projectKey = param.key;
    }
    this.loadProjectData(projectKey);
  });
}
```

In the test I want to check that the project key from the storage is used and not from the URL.

Test:

```js
describe('ProjectPageComponent', () => {
  let component: ProjectPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProjectPageComponent>;
  let route: ActivatedRoute;

  const mockStorageService = {
    saveItem: jest.fn(),
    getItem: jest.fn(),
    removeItem: jest.fn(),
    removeAll: jest.fn()
  };

  const mockActivatedRoute = {
    params: {
      subscribe: jest.fn()
    }
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      ...
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute },
        { provide: StorageService, useValue: mockStorageService }
      ]
      ...
    })
  });

  it('when project key is not in URL but in storage, should use project key from storage', fakeAsync(done => {
    mockStorageService.getItem.mockImplementation(() => 'FOO1');
    jest
      .spyOn(mockActivatedRoute.params, 'subscribe')
      .mockReturnValue(of(EMPTY));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    mockActivatedRoute.params.subscribe(param => {
      expect(component.loadProjectData).toHaveBeenCalledWith('FOO2'); // should return false in case of 'FOO2', but always returns true
      done();
    });
  }));
...
```

In the routing the project is passed via `project/:key`, but for this test the key should be null.

The test always succeeds, but why?

Comment: I'd guess because you have another test where it *is* called with `'FOO2'` - your mocks seem to be shared between tests, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61464226/3001761 for options to avoid this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, currently this is the only test, but thanks for the hint!

Comment: Can you put *anything* in that callback that makes the test fail? Maybe it's not being reached, although you are injecting the done function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, strangely, even a `expect(1).toBe(2);` within the subscription let the test succeed.